# CSS Keyframe Animation Not Working in Firefox (I have looked at other answers)

Tags: html, css, slide, keyframe

I have the same problem ([CSS Keyframe animation working in Chrome, but not FF (or IE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097327/css-keyframe-animation-working-in-chrome-but-not-ff-or-ie)), different animation.

I found that removing the quotes made it work in IE, but still not in Firefox.

```
<div class="media24-titles">
    <div class="photobanner">

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img class="first" src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

<a href="http://www.media24.com/en/newspapers.html" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.legends24.co.za/wp-content/logos/03.jpg" alt=""></a>

    </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">

.photobanner {
height: 60px;
width: 10300px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
overflow:hidden;
}

.photobanner img {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.photobanner img:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-moz-transform: scale(1.1);
-o-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
cursor: pointer;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/*keyframe animations*/

.first {
-webkit-animation: bannermove 120s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: bannermove 120s linear infinite;
-ms-animation: bannermove 120s linear infinite;
-o-animation: bannermove 120s linear infinite;
animation: bannermove 120s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-left: -9125px;
}
}

@-moz-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-left: -9125px;
}
}

@-webkit-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-left: -9125px;
}
}

@-ms-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-left: -9125px;
}
}

@-o-keyframes bannermove {
0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
100% {
    margin-left: -9125px;
}
}
</style>
```

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wilburlikesmith/4yzrpgco/2/

I did notice the use of :first-child, :nth-child(2) and :nth-child(3) which I really hope is not the issue, I have many many many logos to display...

Comment: use marque code for this feature.

Comment: Obsolete, http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element-0 @Sarower

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyframe animation is working in Firefox, but the problem is that you're only moving one image (`.first`), so once that image moves out of the viewport the others stop moving.

The fact that the other images move at all is only by virtue of the fact that they are inline elements, and as the first image moves they move inline with it.

It might work better if you apply your animation to the element that contains all the images (`.photobanner`).

Comment: I should have thought of that... :/ Thanks, giving you the answer since you were first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are moving the first image, you are not applying the animation on all the images, what I did was to set the class `first` on the div with the class `photobanner`, thus the entire row of images is now sliding instead of only the first image, [Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4yzrpgco/3/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Karim, I had to give the answer to @Jonathan_Nicol since his post was first, but thanks for the fiddle :)